# Why (variable of type IEnumerable<SomeThing>).GetType().GetGenericArgsuments().Count() is two instead of one?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Take a look at following code:

Why result1 has 2 generic arguments?

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<Test> result1 = Test1();
            Console.WriteLine(result1.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Count()); // 2

            IEnumerable<Test> result2 = Test2();
            Console.WriteLine(result2.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Count()); // 1
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Test> Test1()
        {
            return new Test[] { }.Where(t => t.Id > 1).Select(t =>
            {
                t.Id++;
                return t;
            });
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Test> Test2()
        {
            return new Test[] { }.Where(t => t.Id > 1);
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because what you get back from Test1 is an instance of a WhereSelectArrayIterator which takes two generic parameters, a source type and a result type. i.e. `class WhereSelectArrayIterator<TSource, TResult>` or see [the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,cffd4efbf86815cb,references).

However the class itself implements IEnumerable<TResult> which allows it to be assigned to your variable. The mistake you're making is confusing the assignable type (which is IEnumerable<Test>) with the implementation type (WhereSelectArrayInterator). When you just have a where statement there's only one generic type as where doesn't convert types from a source to a result.

In this case printing the names of the types would give you the answer.